# passing a Guid from a view back to corresponding controller action

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, view, controller

```
<div class="col1">
@foreach (var item in Model.ListApplications.Select((model) => new { model }))
{
    <div class="col1">
        <fieldset>
            <p><span class="bold-text">Application ID: </span>@item.model.ApplicationId</p>

            <p><span class="bold-text">First Name: </span>@item.model.FirstName</p>

            <p><span class="bold-text">Last Name: </span>@item.model.LastName</p>

            <p><span class="bold-text">Programme Name: </span>@item.model.ProgrammeDesc</p>

            <p><input id="submit-button" class="form-submit-button" type="submit" value="continue application" /></p>                        
        </fieldset>
    </div>
}   
</div>
```

The code above is found on a page for selecting previously started applications that a user can select to continue filling in. When the submit button is clicked, the Application Id for the specific application needs to be returned to this controller action:

```
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult PreviousApplications(ListApplicationViewModel model)
    {
        return RedirectToAction("PersonalDetails");
    }
```

A user could potentially have multiple applications.

How do I go about implementing this?

Comment: Is your class="col1" div in the form tag?

Comment: yes it's inside of a @{ Html.BeginForm(); } and @{ Html.EndForm(); } section which once compiled is displayed as a form tag

Comment: Did you use Html.Hidden()? It work me always very well

Comment: yes that works I created a @Html.Hidden with the name set as ApplicationId and set the value as the ApplicationId Guid on post back I then assigned the value to an ApplicationId value in the viewmodel

Comment: Was your problem fixed after using Html.Hidden()?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you use *@Html.Hidden()* or *@Html.HiddenFor()* ? It works me always very well
for example

```
@Html.HiddenFor(@item.model.ApplicationId)
```